# concatenate multiple columns but avoid 2 cell if one cell is in blank or null in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have fetched the record from a table like this:

```
ITEMNum     NounMod                 Att                         AttVal              attuom

13009029    ABRASIVE,OILSTONE       LENGTH                      150                 MM
13009029    ABRASIVE,OILSTONE       WIDTH                       25                  MM
13009029    ABRASIVE,OILSTONE       HEIGHT                      50                  MM
13009029    ABRASIVE,OILSTONE       GRIT        
13009029    ABRASIVE,OILSTONE       MAKE                        UNION ABRASIVES 
13009029    ABRASIVE,OILSTONE       ADDITIONAL INFORMATION      SILICON CARBIDE 
13009029    ABRASIVE,OILSTONE       TYPE        
13009029    ABRASIVE,OILSTONE       APPLICATION     
13009029    ABRASIVE,OILSTONE       SHAPE       
13009029    ABRASIVE,OILSTONE       STANDARD        
13009029    ABRASIVE,OILSTONE       SPECIAL FEATURES        
13012840    ADAPTER,COMMUNICATION   TYPE                        CURRENT LOOP 
13012840    ADAPTER,COMMUNICATION   CONDUCTOR       
13012840    ADAPTER,COMMUNICATION   ELECTRICAL RATING           24                  VDC
13012840    ADAPTER,COMMUNICATION   NUMBER OF PINS      
13012840    ADAPTER,COMMUNICATION   SPECIAL FEATURES        
13012840    ADAPTER,COMMUNICATION   MAKE        
13012840    ADAPTER,COMMUNICATION   MODEL                       ST5011  
13012840    ADAPTER,COMMUNICATION   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION      20MA,1X
```

I want to concat values like below:

```
ItemNum     LongDes

13009029    ABRASIVE,OILSTONE,LENGTH:150 MM;WIDTH:25 MM;HEIGHT:50 MM;MAKE:UNION ABRASIVES;ADDITIONAL 
        INFORMATION:SILICON CARBIDE STONE
13012840    ADAPTER,COMMUNICATION,TYPE:CURRENT LOOP INTERFACE;ELECTRICAL RATING:24 
        VDC;MODEL:ST5011;ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:20MA,1X
```

Can any one help me to solve this, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your data is unreadable. Use sample data but make the table structure and your requirement clear.

Comment: kindly check now- @mkRabbani

Comment: Plz help me guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MSSQL STUFF as below to achieve your required output-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c985544cb06deaeab6184ea4cdf70ff)

```
    A.ITEMNum,
abc = 
A.NounMod +','+
STUFF((
        SELECT ';' + Att+','+AttVal+','+attuom
        FROM your_table
        WHERE ITEMNum = A.ITEMNum AND NounMod = A.NounMod
        AND NOT (AttVal = '' AND attuom = '')
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '')
FROM your_table A
GROUP BY A.ITEMNum,A.NounMod
```

I have considered '' for your blank column as below-

```
AND NOT (AttVal = '' AND attuom = '')
```

But if you have NULL, just use-

```
AND NOT (AttVal IS NULL AND attuom IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

I put SOME of your data into a table variable (I didn't put it all in, just the fine point between having enough to show this working, and keeping my sanity):

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ITEMNum INT, NounMod VARCHAR(50), Att VARCHAR(50), AttVal VARCHAR(50), attuom VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 13009029, 'ABRASIVE,OILSTONE', 'LENGTH', '150', 'MM';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 13009029, 'ABRASIVE,OILSTONE', 'WIDTH', '25', 'MM';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 13009029, 'ABRASIVE,OILSTONE', 'HEIGHT', '50', 'MM';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 13009029, 'ABRASIVE,OILSTONE', 'GRIT', NULL, NULL;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 13012840, 'ADAPTER,COMMUNICATION', 'TYPE', 'CURRENT LOOP', NULL;
```

Then I wrote this query to give you what you asked for:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ITEMNum, NounMod, NounMod AS LongDes FROM @table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ITEMNum, NounMod, CONCAT(Att, ';', AttVal, ' ', ISNULL(attuom, '')) AS LongDes FROM @table WHERE AttVal IS NOT NULL)
SELECT ITEMNum, LongDes = STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + LongDes FROM cte c1 WHERE c1.ITEMNum = c2.ITEMNum 
    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') FROM cte c2 GROUP BY ITEMNum;
```

Results are (remember I didn't put ALL the data in):

```
ITEMNum     LongDes
13009029    ABRASIVE,OILSTONE,LENGTH;150 MM,WIDTH;25 MM,HEIGHT;50 MM
13012840    ADAPTER,COMMUNICATION,TYPE;CURRENT LOOP
```

There's a few things going on there, so here's some pointers:

- you seem to want the item description `NounMod` as part of the description, so I used a `UNION` to get this and the other descriptions into a list, a list where I ignore NULL values in the `AttVal` column;
- I use `FOR XML PATH` to make this into a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `STRING_AGG()`:

```
select itemnum, nounmod,
       concat(NounMod, string_agg(concat(att, (':' + AttVal)), ' '))
from t
group by itemnum, nounmod;
```

Note that `CONCAT()` ignores `NULL` values whereas `+` would return `NULL`.

Comment: @Tinku . . . This is a much better solution than `for xml path`, assuming your database supports `string_agg()`.